# Read Table outputed by SQL Server Stored Proc during each iteration of While loop

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net

I am executing a stored procedure and inside the stored procedure there is a WHILE loop. Every time an iteration occurs in the WHILE loop it outputs a table (showing its progress). I would like to capture this table and read it in .NET (using .NET SQLClient driver). I would like to be able to read this progress table AS the table is generated (like in SSMS) and NOT when the stored procedure is finished running.

PS: I don't care what .NET language you like - solution or ideas in any language would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've come up with a way to do this.  I started by creating a small local database with a single table, called Table1 that has a text column named status.  I also created a StoredProcedure called StoredProcedure1.  It looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.StoredProcedure1
/*
(
@parameter1 int = 5,
@parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
)
*/ AS
declare @setCount int 
declare @result table (cnt int)
set @setCount = 0

insert into Table1 (status) VALUES ('Starting');

while @setCount < 5
begin
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:03';

    insert into @result (cnt)
    select @setCount
    set @setCount = @setCount + 1;

    update Table1 set status='Iteration ' + cast(@setCount as varchar);
end

RETURN
```

The stored procedure simply inserts a starting status value into Table1, and then loops through 5 iterations, delaying three seconds for each iteration to simulate a long running process.  At the end of each iteration, the status field is updated to reflect the next iteration running.

Next I created a WindowsForms project with a single form that has a single label.  I created a private method to execute the stored procedure as a long running process.

```
    Private Sub LongRunningProcess()
    Dim _conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MARS_ProcTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("exec StoredProcedure1", _conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    _conn.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    _conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Then I created another method that will check the status in table1 until the stored procedure has completed.

```
Private Sub StatusChecker()
    Dim _conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MARS_ProcTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;")
    Dim cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("select status from Table1", _conn)
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    _conn.Open()

    While Not _done
        Dim stat As String

        stat = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

        If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
            Me.Invoke(Sub()
                          Me.Label1.Text = stat
                      End Sub)
        Else
            Me.Label1.Text = stat
        End If
    End While

    _conn.Close()

End Sub
```

I added a simple method to flip a private boolean on the form class to true when LongRunningProcess is complete.

```
Private Sub FinishProcess()
    '_done is a private variable on the form class.
    _done = True
End Sub
```

Finally, in the form's Load event, I use .NET's task library to kick off the status checker and the long running process, ensuring that the LongRunningProcess task is continued with the finishing process.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf StatusChecker)
    Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf LongRunningProcess).ContinueWith(AddressOf FinishProcess)

End Sub
```

So when this all runs, we have background threads running the long task and checking the status as often as needed.  Since the stored procedure is updating Table1 with information and executing those statements in different transactions, you see the updates as they happen.